# Automate the Boring Stuff, Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, input

I copied the code that Al Sweitgart gave in his Lesson 3 video Automate the boring stuff. I get an error when I run the module saying

> unexpected EOF when parsing

On the last line, I tried to write

```
print('You will be " + str(int(MyAge + 1) + " in a year.')
```

The code would then run, but it wouldn't add the age and would show the string:

```
You will be " + str(int(MyAge + 1) + " in a year.
```

This program says hello and asks for my name :

```
print ('Hello World!')
print ('What is your name?') # ask for their name
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))

print('What is your age?') #ask for their age
myAge = input()
print('You will be ' + str(int(MyAge + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

If the user inputs `29` for the age, the output should be

```
You will be 30 in a year.
```

and NOT

```
You will be " + str(int(MyAge + 1) + " in a year.
```

Comment: Your final line has three open parentheses, but only two closing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Note the use of int on the second last line and the removal of int on the last line.

```
# This program says hello and asks for my  name

print ('Hello World!')

print ('What is your name?') # ask for their name
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))

print('What is your age?') #ask for their age
myAge = int(input()) # CASTING TO AN INT ON THIS LINE 
print('You will be ' + str(myAge + 1) + ' in a year.') # CHANGING TO A STRING ON THIS 
# LINE AND REMOVING THE INT FUNCTION
```